# Decode unicode chracters in HTML in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a string that represents an HTML block. All the unicode characters are encoded. So it takes lots of spaces when inserted to database.
For example: `<p>thích</p>` is saved as `<p>th&iacute;ch</p>`
How can I decode those unicode characters? I cannot use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode because it will decode some other characters like > or < as well, which I still want it to be encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just manually re-encoding the non-unicode specific characters?

```
Server.HtmlDecode(str).Replace("<","&lt;")
                      .Replace(">","&gt;")
                      .Replace("&","&amp;")
                      .Replace("\"","&quot;")
                      .Replace("\'","&#39;")
```

Comment: Could you tell me what is included in "whatever else"?

Comment: I mean what must be encoded in order to be displayed correctly?
Are the followings sufficient?
& → &amp;
< → &lt;
> → &gt;
" → &quot;

Comment: I would add `' → &#39;` and that's it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That's fine. Just need to move replacement of & before anything else.